# Printing a list of tuples in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I am trying to print a list of tuples into my html Flask template, but I am getting this error:

```
self.name, self.filename)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I put the `localhost` address in my browser

How can I print my data onto the browser?

CODE:
eslJobs.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template    
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def chinaJobs():
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.eslcafe.com/jobs/china/').read()

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')

    dl = soup.dl

    chinaAds = []
    china = []

    for words in dl.find_all('a'):
        links = words.get('href')
        link_text = words.text

        if 'university' in link_text.lower():
            chinaAds.append([links, link_text])

        if 'college' in link_text.lower():
            chinaAds.append([links, link_text])

    for ad in chinaAds:
        china.append(tuple(ad))
        return render_template("eslJobs.html", china=china)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

CODE:
eslJobs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ESL Jobs</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>College &amp; University ESL Jobs</h1>
</div>


<ul class="list-group">
{% for href, caption in {{ china }}: %}
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a>  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u post full traceback error message?, not clear to me where to correlate it to your posted code.

Comment: @IronFist The error message is very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to fix this line:

```
{% for href, caption in {{ china }}: %}
```

to

```
{% for href, caption in china %}
```

***Bonus***:

This code

```
for words in dl.find_all('a'):
    links = words.get('href')
    link_text = words.text

    if 'university' in link_text.lower():
        chinaAds.append([links, link_text])

    if 'college' in link_text.lower():
        chinaAds.append([links, link_text])

for ad in chinaAds:
    china.append(tuple(ad))
```

can all be optimized to:

```
for words in dl.find_all('a'):
    links = words.get('href')
    link_text = words.text
    link_lower = link_text.lower()

    if ('university' in link_lower) or ('college' in link_lower):
        chinaAds.append((links, link_text))
```

Then just render `chinaAds`:

```
#fix indentation of your return statement, on your actual code
#it seems belonging to the for loop
return render_template("eslJobs.html", china=chinaAds)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `For` usage in [`jinja` document](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-control-structures).

```
<h1>Members</h1>
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
  <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

---

Therefore, you don't need the double brace in your template where inside a `{%  %}`, you can just delete it.

```
{% for href, caption in china : %}
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ href }}">{{ caption }}</a>  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

---

In your python script, there is an indentation error, that prevent you from getting the full list.

```
for ad in chinaAds:
    china.append(tuple(ad))
return render_template("eslJobs.html", china=china)
```

Comment: Haha! Ok.  That's awesome. I added another for loop as well to print out the full list.  Thanks!

Comment: I have modified my answer. You can get the full list.